# GNU Screen won't inherit my PATH on 10.5.8

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I use screen on a daily basis for my terminal needs and I'm quite happy with it.  Recently, though, I made some updates to my bash configuration files and I noticed that I was setting various `PATH` elements (`PATH`, `MANPATH`, `INFOPATH`, etc) in 2 places.  I modified the files to be what they should be and now all of my environment variables get set once in `.bash_profile`.  Herein lies my problem.

Apparently, the reason I was setting them in two places was because of screen.  screen appears to only execute `.bashrc` and does *not* appear to inherit my `PATH` or any other environment variables correctly from my original bash shell.  Because it only executes `.bashrc` and I now set my variables in `.bash_profile` only, I get an incomplete `PATH`.

My question, then, is how to get my environment variables into screen without the duplication.  Reading through the `Bash` docs seems to indicate that it could be [the kind of shell that screen uses to log in, i.e. a non-login interactive shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) but I couldn't figure out how to force screen to use a particular kind of shell, only the shell to use via `-s /bin/bash`.

You can peruse my config files at [my GitHub page](http://github.com/timvisher/bash_configuration).  [This is the commit commit that broke screen](http://github.com/timvisher/bash_configuration/commit/d998a7e2f932582ffc61e380909514d9fb59e3ed).

**EDIT:** I'm using `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06` and I tend to invoke it by `screen -h 50000`

**EDIT:** I've now been able to test this on Cygwin (`CYGWIN_NT-5.1 1.7.1(0.218/5/3) i686`, `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`) and it exhibits different behavior than on my Mac.

The specific behavior that I've now discovered is that in Cygwin the changes that I make to `PATH` in .bash_profile are duplicated upon entering screen and then successive creation of screen windows do not duplicate the path but do re-source .bash_profile.

To illustrate the behavior I'm talking about:

Output from a fresh terminal:

```
...

PATH: /home/tvishe01/bin/emacs/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/groovy-1.6.1/bin:/usr/lib/lapack

MANPATH: /home/tvishe01/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man::/usr/ssl/man

Aliases:
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'

...

[~]$
```

Output from the first invocation of screen:

```
[~]$ screen -h 50000 -s -/bin/bash

...

PATH: /home/tvishe01/bin/emacs/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin/emacs/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/groovy-1.6.1/bin:/usr/lib/lapack

MANPATH: /home/tvishe01/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/home/tvishe01/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man::/usr/ssl/man:/usr/ssl/man

Aliases:
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'

...

[~]$
```

Subsequent calls to `C-a c`:

```
...

PATH: /home/tvishe01/bin/emacs/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin/emacs/bin:/home/tvishe01/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/groovy-1.6.1/bin:/usr/lib/lapack

MANPATH: /home/tvishe01/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/home/tvishe01/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man::/usr/ssl/man:/usr/ssl/man

Aliases:
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'

...

[~]$
```

You can see

Comment: The duplication is because you have *bash* configured to unconditionally add these entries with it is a ‘login’ shell, and you are telling *screen* to invoke *bash* as a ‘login’ shell. I have rewritten my answer to try to address the general issues of shells, *screen*, and environment variables.

Answer (score 17):

## *screen* and Environment Variables

By default, *screen* passes along to its shells (and other processes) whatever environment variables it had when the session was started (i.e. reconnecting does not change which environment variables are given to new shells). But because both *screen* and shells' configuration files commonly change environment variables, there are many places where unexpected changes can be introduced. There are a few variables, like *TERM*, that *screen* it almost always changes, but these are generally required for the functionality that *screen* provides.

Let's say that neither your shell's configuration, nor *screen*'s configuration will modify a variable named *FOOBAR* (fairly likely, all in all). If you start a session with `FOOBAR=foo screen`, then all the shells created in that session will have an environment variable named *FOOBAR* with a value of `foo`.

Things get more complicated for variables that either *screen* or your shell might modify.

## Missing Settings When Using *screen*

### Login Shells

If you find that some settings are missing in shells started by *screen*, it may be because your shell is configured only to update those settings for ‘login’ shells. Most shells understand a special convention (in C: `**argv == '-'`) that *screen* can be configured to use.

Per the [*screen* documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Shell.html#Shell):

> **shell** *command*
>
> Set  the  command to be used to create a new shell.  This overrides the
>      value of the environment variable $SHELL.  This is useful if you'd like
>      to  run a tty-enhancer which is expecting to execute the program speci-
>      fied in $SHELL. If the command begins with a '-' character,  the  shell
>      will be started as a login-shell.

To have *screen* start shells as ‘login’ shells, start *screen* with `screen -s -/bin/bash`, or add this line to your `.screenrc`:

```
shell -/bin/bash
```

Adjust for the path to whatever shell you happen to be using.

## *screen* Configuration

Missing or reset environment variables could also be due to `setenv` and `unsetenv` commands in a *screen* configuration file. You will have to check both the *.screenrc* in your home directory and whichever file your compilation of *screen* is using as the ‘system screenrc’ (you might try a command like `strings "$(which screen)" | fgrep -i screenrc` to find the pathname that was configured at compile time–it is usually */etc/screenrc* for a system-installed *screen*; add-on installations will probably use some other pathname). You can use `SCREENRC=/dev/null SYSSCREENRC=/dev/null screen` to temporarily avoid these settings files, but there is a compile-time option that prevents the effective use  of *SYSSCREENRC* (presumably so that system administrators can force some bit of initial configuration).

## Duplicate Settings When Using *screen*

It is fairly common to add items to an environment variable like *PATH* in a shell's configuration file(s) so that the updated value is available to normal shell sessions (e.g. *xterm* or other terminal windows, console sessions, etc.). If such items are added in a shell's per-shell configuration (or, if you are using the `-/path/to/shell` setting described above, in the shells per-login configuration) then the shell started by *screen* will likely have multiple copies of the added items.

One strategy to avoid this is to put all additions to variables like *PATH* in the per-login configuration of your shell and avoid using the `-/path/to/shell` shell setting with *screen*.

Another strategy is to only conditionally add the new items to the variable. Depending on the shell, the code to do this can be a bit complicated, but it can usually be encapsulated in a shell function for easy use.

Yet another strategy is to always start with a fixed value in your configuration files. This can sometimes cause problems when moving your configuration files from system to system when the default values might vary significantly.

## Diagnostics

If you can not directly spot where a particular modification is happening, you can try the following to track down where the change is happening.

Check the current value in your initial shell:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

Check how the shell itself modifies the value when a sub-shell is created:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'
```

Check how the shell modifies the value when a ‘login’ sub-shell is created:

```
perl -e '$s=shift;exec {$s} "-$s", @ARGV or die "unable to start shell"' /bin/bash
echo "$PATH"
exit
```

Check how *screen* modifies the value:

```
printf '#!/bin/sh\nl=/tmp/echo-var.log;rm -f "$l"; echo $PATH >"$l"' >/tmp/echo-var &&
chmod a+x /tmp/echo-var &&
screen -s /tmp/echo-var &&
cat /tmp/echo-var.log
```

Comment: This solves part of my problem. Unfortunately it doesn't go the full way. Now, screen is working fine run with `screen -s -/bin/bash` but it doesn't behave as I've come to expect it to behave under Cygwin on my work machine. On that machine, I run `screen -h 50000` and it simply inherits my `PATH` without actually sourcing the file again. This runs both every time I launch a new window.

Comment: The environment of the *screen* process should always be inherited by any its its children (except for stuff like TERM that it might override). Try `FOOBAR=baz screen` and check `echo $FOOBAR` in the shell windows from `screen` and `screen -s -/bin/bash`. Both variations should have `FOOBAR` = `baz`. If your `PATH` is being modified, then you will have to track down what is doing it. Try `SYSSCREENRC=/dev/null SCREENRC=/dev/null screen`, if that lets your `PATH` through, then it is probably a `setenv PATH` in `/etc/screenrc` or `~/.screenrc`. Otherwise it is something your `.bashrc` is doing.

Comment: I have done a large rewrite of / addition to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The last time I saw a similar issue, I solved it by using `screen -l` when starting screen.

You can use the `-l` option when invoking `screen` (turn [login mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Login) on; also controlled by the `deflogin` and `login` commands in `.screenrc`) to set whether screen should log the window in by default (adding/removing the /etc/utmp entry).

Login mode is on by default, but that can be changed at compile time.  If screen isn't compiled with utmp support these commands are not available.

I don't seem to need the `-l` mode in Debian Lenny's default screen (v4.0.3); it seems to be on by default.  My `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` are getting read correctly.  How are you invoking `screen`?  What version are you using?

Comment: tho under this theory, `screen -ln` should *not* run my `~/.profile`, and it still gets run.  so try the `-l` flag, but this probably isn't the right answer.  will leave it here for the moment.

Comment: It seems that `-l` only controls whether `screen` adds an entry to the `utmp` file, not whether it invokes new shells with their own `-l` option or uses the exec-with-`-`-prefix custom.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with launchd behavior on Leopard.  See this MacPorts bug report for screen on Leopard to see why it's not going to ever be fixed unless you can somehow backport Snow Leopard's launchd.

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/18235#comment:26

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with sourcing your .bashrc from within .bash_profile.  If you are only using your machine locally your .bash_profile will in most cases only be sourced when you do your initial login (there are obviously other times it gets sourced).

I organize my files so that if I want something to be done only when I login, I put the information in .bash_profile and for everything else I put them in .bashrc.  PATH is one thing I put in my .bashrc, and I source .bashrc in my .bash_profile.

Comment: Would you be comfortable posting your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files somewhere so that I could see them?  The problem I ran into while doing something similar was that `PATH` would grow every time I would create a new screen instance because it would inherit the old `PATH` and then re-add everything again.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I didn't see this...

I've changed a lot of things around so they won't make a lot of sense, but this is basically what I do.

# .bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi


Then I put everything else in .bashrc, except for things that I want to start when I first login, which also go in .bash_profile.

PATH is handled in .bashrc as a series of lines instead of one path definition like most do

export PATH=/path/to/binaries1:$PATH
export PATH=/path/to/binaries2:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have some problem like that I create a file `$HOME/.debug` and in all of the files sourced/executed during login/shell invocation
(e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, etc)
I have as the first line

```
test -f $HOME/.debug && echo $HOME/.bashrc 1>&2
```

or similar. For specific debugging you can also add things like

```
test -f $HOME/.debug && echo PATH now equals $PATH 1>&2
```

This way you can be 100% absolutely certain what files that are or not are used.

The redirect to stderr is important, you do not want something messing up stdout in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can stay with .profile since system does not touch bashrc (like graphics session)
Now you simply have two different sets of environment - one from .profile, other for bash from .bashrc.