# PATH not set in GNU Screen, OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, shell, gnu-screen

I'm not a regular user of `screen` but every few weeks I use for some delicate tasks.
However yesterday when starting I was unable to execute any command (`ls`, `ssh`, `mkdir`), quick debugging revealed that the environment variable `PATH` was not set correctly.

More specifically `echo $PATH` shows my customized dirs set in `.profile` but missing the very basic entries like `/usr/local/bin`.

On "normal" terminal everything is fine, just in `screen` it's different. I suspect `screen` uses a different shell then default OS X Terminal app as prefix is `bash-3.2$` (as opposed to `username$`) and I've tried diagnostics as found in this answer to a similar question: https://superuser.com/a/114314/127409

However I've never modified any of screen's settings and though shell was different I've never had any issues like this. The only thing I can think of causing troubles is recent OS X update (10.8 to 10.9) but I couldn't find further information in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a change in "login shell" behaviour. Read up on the different startup files bash uses - .bashrc, /etc/bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile, /etc/profile, ... - in "man bash", and until you've figured out what changed in the system-wide defaults, check /etc/screenrc and .screenrc for the "login" setting. If unset, the default may have changed, too.

To play around with the setting, from within screen (assuming you use the default Ctrl-A command binding), hit `^A:` to get a prompt and enter `login on` or `login off` and, after setting it, create a new window with `^Ac` to see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda forgot about my question - also I don't have any OS X around me any more so I don't know what caused the original problem. Anyway thanks a lot for the `login *` hint.